# ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I got this "stacktrace" when trying to display my website. I am new to this, but the error looks to be to something regarding the laravel's system-files?

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
Class App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist
in Container.php line 737
at ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController') in      Container.php line 737
at Container->build('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', array()) in       Container.php line 627
at Container->make('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', array()) in  Application.php line 674
 at Application->make('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController') in   ControllerDispatcher.php line 85
 at ControllerDispatcher- >makeController('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController') in  ControllerDispatcher.php line 57
 at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', 'index') in Route.php line 201
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php     line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in    VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'),  array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in   StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in  AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/var/www/html/app/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

This is my route.php file. 
    //(php open tag) Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

and my HomeController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {

public function index()
     {
            return view ('hello');
    }

}
```

And this is my view file hello.php

```html
<doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Laravel 5</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to Laravel 5
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same issue for some authentication matter. I get solution by following the 2 steps below:

```
1. Put "league/oauth2-server": "4.1.*" on the require section of your composer.json file. 
2. run 'composer update' command on terminal.
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;` with `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` and also do

> composer dump-autoload

Comment: I still got the error.  I did the change you told me to do, and run the composer dump-autoload,and then: php artisan serve